# Can I apply for a UnionPay card while traveling in China?

Tags: china, payment-cards

I'm now in China and found that so many stores only accept UnionPay even if they insist on accepting *credit cards*. For example today I ate at a local shop in Shanghai, which I went to ***because I was told I can use a credit card***, but when I checked the staff there said they can accept UnionPay only.

So I want to get a UnionPay card. But it seems that there doesn't exist any description on [the official page](http://en.unionpay.com). Also, according to [Travel China Guide](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/faq/when/money.htm), it is too hard to create a credit card in China as a traveler.

Can I apply for a Chinese credit card?

Answer: Yes, you can, if you work in China or have steady income. But it is impossible for travelers. I don't know whether he or she talks about UnionPay nor what the *"steady income"* means.

Is it possible to create a UnionPay, and if so how can I do?

---

Notice: *I know my home country issues it but I wouldn't open it since I had a history of too much overdue. In fact I failed to open Visa/MasterCard at all the applications I made after the overdue.*

Comment: I'll try to answer later on but seriously, why not just pay cash? The answer in any case will be that it's forbiddingly difficult and not worth the hassle. Are you staying only in Shanghai or also other places and for how long? Do you speak some Chinese?

Comment: @mts For one, I don't like to carry my wallet. I use a card-holding iPhone 6 case (up to 4 cards) and I definitely like it. For another, I have a pathological hatred for touching the cash (especially coins) as I can't tolerate the odor after touching it... I stay in Shanghai only for 2 weeks but because I really like it, I will come back again. I don't speak, but I can read a bit.

Comment: @dda Is "entered" not correct and why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Can I apply for UnionPay card while traveling for China?**

Yes you can. And it seems easier than I thought. How? Read on...

**Is it a good idea for a traveler to do so?**

Likely not. Most of China runs on cash. You have to open a bank account. In China. It is not as hard as it sounds but be warned:

> First, I would not recommend opening a bank account in China to a foreigner that is only staying in China temporarily; it is primarily beneficial to those that are going to be residing in China for a relatively long period of time.

from [an expat guide](http://www.shanghaiexpat.com/blog/community/business-and-career/expat-guide-chinese-banking-23532.html) while [another such guide has a whole paragraph on why not to open a bank account in China.](http://www.travelchinacheaper.com/open-china-bank-account)

### How to get a UnionPay card?

You read right, you need to open a bank account and at that occasion insist on getting  a UnionPay card.

**Which bank to choose?**

You are advised to choose a big bank over a rural one for service that is at least partially in English. Bank of China (BOC), ICBC and China Merchants Bank come recommended among others. 
Chose a bank with a branch you can easily reach, you never know.

**How to open a bank account?**

Take your passport, some cash (100RMB should suffice easily but take some more if you want to charge your card right after. It will work like a debit card, so do not expect to be able to overdraw) and ideally a friend who could translate for you. That would greatly facilitate the process but I'll assume you are on your own for the rest. Alternatively you could call branches beforehand and ask (or have hotel staff ask for you) when there is English-speaking staff around. Again, I'll assume you are on your own.

- Go to the bank you chose. You have to take a number but these have categories so ask staff for which one you need (usually there is some security / welcoming staff around, if not ask anyone. If you're lucky there even is an info desk.). The magic phrase is

  > “我想开一个银行账户” – Wǒ xiǎng kāi yīgè yínháng zhànghù
  >   I'd like to open a bank account.

  or just say "kāi zhànghù" if you're not that friendly with Chinese.
- Get your number. Wait for your number to show up on a screen and go to the appropriate desk. Bring something to read for the wait in case.
- Maybe they gave you the form already and again if you are lucky it has English on it. Still your best bet is to ask the staff fill in all of that stuff once it is your turn. **Make sure they spell your name correctly** (i.e. as it is in your passport).
- They will need your passport (and only that). They might cringe when they see you are on a tourist visa, but it is not an issue, I have done it. Insist in case, worst case go to another bank or branch. You will need to tell them an address and likely a better strategy is to give them your hotel address (but no need telling them it's a hotel) than a home address in a faraway country. I can't remember having received any bank letters but then maybe that's my memory or I did not care back then.
- They should issue you a UnionPay card in any case but no harm asking explicitly. Wait for them to complete the administrative process. They likely make a copy of your passport but will not keep it. You will be asked to choose and enter repeatedly a six-digit PIN.
- At the end you will get your card, paperwork and possibly other stuff for online-banking. Try to get a basic explanation of how to use the card but you should be good already.

You can now fill up your card with cash at their ATMs (only some of the ATMs also accept cash, so choose the right one) and use your card - right away if I remember correctly.

Sources and further reading:

- [foreignercn.com: Opening Bank Accounts in China](http://www.foreignercn.com/index.php?option=com_content&id=5637:opening-bank-accounts-in-china&catid=43:housing-a-finance&Itemid=44)
- [Shanghai Expat: Expat Guide to Chinese Banking](http://www.shanghaiexpat.com/blog/community/business-and-career/expat-guide-chinese-banking-23532.html)
- [Travel China Cheaper: HOW TO OPEN A CHINA BANK ACCOUNT](http://www.travelchinacheaper.com/open-china-bank-account)

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm... I think the next time I visit I consider opening it. I have only 3 days remained in my current trip.

Comment: I can confirm it works as @mts says. I got two cards like this, with Bank of Construction and Bank of China, in Shenzhen.

Comment: @dda When did you get the Bank of China card? They reject the application by travelers, as they require you to submit the residence permit.

Comment: A few months ago.

Comment: Of course another solution is that after you get a bank account, you create a WeChat account, and link your WeChat Pay account to your bank account.

Comment: China runs on cash? No China runs on Mobile payments not cash

Comment: China runs on alipay

Answer (score 10):

The answer by @mts gives a good guide on how to get a UnionPay card while inside China. However there's an easier alternative back if you live in the US: apply for a [Discover](https://www.discover.com/online-banking/) card. Wiki [mentions that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_UnionPay):

> In May 2005 Discover Network announced an alliance with China UnionPay Network. The two companies have signed a long-term agreement that **allows acceptance of Discover Network brand cards at UnionPay ATMs and point-of-sale terminals in China** and acceptance of China UnionPay cards on the PULSE network in the U.S.

You can also [apply for a UnionPay credit card](https://www.icbc-us.com/ICBC/%E6%B5%B7%E5%A4%96%E5%88%86%E8%A1%8C/%E5%B7%A5%E9%93%B6%E7%BE%8E%E5%9B%BD%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99/EN/ProductsServices/Creditcard/Browsecreditcards/browsecreditcards.htm) from ICBC's branch in the US. Both options require you to have an SSN and some credit history.

Some other banks outside the US are now starting to offer UnionPay cards too, for example [this Russian bank](https://www.gazprombank.ru/personal/cards/745947/) can issue one.

Comment: That's a +1 right there. Where is the quote from? Any chance of getting such a card from outside the US?

Comment: @mts only US citizens and residents are eligible, so no

Comment: Discover has a similar arrangement with DIners Club that I have used, with intermittent success, in Europe.

Comment: It's interesting to hear, though unfortunately I'm not in US.

Comment: JCB also has such an agreement w/ UnionPay. JCB cards are issued globally, although by only a handful of banks outside of Japan.

Comment: Of course, you still have to convince the store/restaurant payee that a Discover card works as a UnionPay card. If you’re Chinese language abilities are weak, this is likely to be pretty difficult. Do the Discover cards have the UnionPay logo on them?