# Can a traveller use Alipay/Tenpay mobile payments in China?

Tags: china, payment

Can a short-term visitor to China sign up to Alipay (Taobao) or Tenpay (WeChat/QQ) mobile payments, without Chinese ID or a Chinese bank account? If yes, how?

Comment: Would you mind getting a Chinese bank account? Then there sure is [a way to Alipay](http://www.smartshanghai.com/articles/smsh/yes-foreigners-can-use-alipay-this-is-how). As I have answered [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73567/32134) getting a Chinese bank account is not that hard, certainly not for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, and you do not necessarily need a Chinese bank account. You have a few options:

(1) you could add money into your Alipay account using mobile phone refill cards. These refill cards are purchasable at any convenience store or supermarket.

(2) you can get your identity verified with a non-Chinese passport, although it will take 24 hours (it's instant for Chinese Resident ID Card holders). Instructions are [here](http://www.howtotao.com/alipay-personal-account-for-foreign-users/). But 24 hours isn't bad in any sense, anyway.

(3) Alipay is usable at many restaurants and shops in China. I am not sure, but I think using the "pay by QR code scan" functionality requires you to have Fast Pay enabled, which in turn requires you to have a Chinese bank account. If you're just shopping on Taobao, then you don't necessarily need a bank account & UnionPay card.

(4) If you decide you don't want to open a bank account, then you probably wouldn't benefit much from being able to use Alipay. However, any place that accepts Alipay would very likely accept cash, so just bring enough cash with you. And most places where the expense is too big for cash would usually accept major international credit cards.

Comment: +1, just learned something new. Usability of Alipay for foreigners seems to have improved so much over the years. [Here](http://www.howtotao.com/alipay-personal-account-for-foreign-users/) is a step-by-step instruction of how to verify with a passport, confirming your answer. Would you mind including it directly in your answer?

Comment: @mts Sure! Why not?

Comment: @mts that link says you need "Bank card issued by banks located in China Mainland" too.

Comment: @Berwyn Linking a bank account isn't a must. I personally didn't have my Alipay account linked to my bank account when I first opened my Alipay account. However, some nice functionalities do require you to have a Chinese bank account.

Comment: Ok. But can you confirm a foreigner can validate their alipay account using only their passport on that page? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @Berwyn that's how I read the linked page

Comment: @XuanruiQi I awarded you the well-deserved bounty. Just in case you are knowledgeable about this field as well, note that I have put out another bounty for [Outgoing ticket when leaving China by land](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89348/32134).

Comment: @mts Unfortunately, I happen to know close to nothing about Chinese visas because I'm a citizen...But thank you so much!

Comment: @XuanruiQi no problem. Please be around, as you have provided some great answers here already :)

Comment: It turns out that it's not possible to verify _without_ a Chinese bank card. I just tried to do this and even though I've elected to provide a passport, I'm still required to input my bank card number and the cell phone number associated with the bank card.

Comment: @MichaelWu Strange enough. Probably my info is outdated. When I first used Alipay I didn't bother to connect it with my bank card.

Comment: Yeah it seems there’s no way around identity verification these days.

Comment: Looks like things are changing: https://www.zdnet.com/article/alipay-open-to-foreign-visitors-for-first-time/#ftag=CAD-00-10aag7e